# Disappearing Protovis badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, tag-badges

I happened to notice my bronze `protovis` badge disappeared sometime recently. (I was perversely proud of it, as the project has been deprecated, so I figured I'd be the only one to ever get a badge for it.) I can still see 22 answers and 103 points on [my user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380487/nrabinowitz?tab=tags), which should fit the bill, so where did it go?

I'm not really complaining, just curious, as it doesn't seem like anything changed to reduce my votes or answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tag badges are only awarded on tags which have at least 100 questions under them. The [protovis](/questions/tagged/protovis) tag recently dropped below that threshold (it currently has 99 questions) so the badge was revoked. Whenever the tag reaches 100 questions again, you should get it back.

Comment: Mystery solved. Thanks!

Comment: /me fights down strong incentive to go ask a spurious Protovis question...